Accessing JSON items with Handlebars
I am attempting to render the results of a get request on the financialmodelingprep API into handlebars.
When I use {{results}} on the rendered view, the raw response is as follows:

[ { "symbol": "K", "name": "Kellogg Company", "price": 60.51, "changesPercentage": -1.2565, "change": -0.77, "dayLow": 59.565, "dayHigh": 61.135, "yearHigh": 67.16432, "yearLow": 47.63, "marketCap": 20687400840, "priceAvg50": 56.1392, "priceAvg200": 55.386345, "exchange": "NYSE", "volume": 4363751, "avgVolume": 3451275, "open": 61, "previousClose": 61.28, "eps": 2.36, "pe": 25.64, "earningsAnnouncement": "2024-08-01T04:00:00.000+0000", "sharesOutstanding": 341884000, "timestamp": 1714766402 } ]

However, when I try {{#each}} or {{#if}} I get nothing on the rendered page.
The index.js code is as follows:
router.post('/quote', function (req, res, next) {
  
  request(fullUrl, function (error, response, results) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      fs.writeFile('data/quotes/' + symbol + ".json", results, function (err) {
        console.log(results)
        console.log("The file was saved as " + symbol + ".json");
        res.render('quoteresults', { results });
        if (err) {

          return console.log(err);
        }

      });

    }

  });

});

I have tried the following in the rendered template:
{{#if results}}
<li>{{results.symbol}}
{{/if}}

and
{{#each results
{{name}}
{{/each}}

How can I access each item in the JSON with handlebars?

Have a look at this handlebars template  It's using node, but I think you'll easily see what's up.

The {{#each results}} example should work unless there is something about results that you have not shared.

Have you parsed the JSON string of results? Perhaps what you need is: es.render('quoteresults', { results: JSON.parse(results) });
